# SEO Structured Data: How to reference an advertising agency?

Tags: schema.org

I have to do SEO on a web page for an advertising business. However, schema.org does not seem to know advertising agencies or publicity companies (as subclasses of LocalBusiness or Organization). At least I didn't find anything.

Has anybody got an idea what I could use?

Comment: Why not just use `LocalBusiness` then?

Comment: Because that's not much use. It just gives Google the information that the page is about a business. I would like to give as specific information as possible. Contrasting the wealth of specific categories within the medical field, for instance (https://schema.org/MedicalBusiness) I found it really odd that for advertising and publicity, which is big business after all, there is not a single category. So I thought I must have overlooked something, so I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the Corporation itemType (or Organization if it isn't incorporated) and then the additionalType itemProp with `http://www.productontology.org/doc/Advertising_agency` as the value until there is something better. You can recommend additions to the Schema.org vocabulary at https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues.

Comment: Yes, Corporation sounds better than LocalBusiness. Can you tell me how I would use the itemProp you are suggesting with JSON-LD? It looks to me as if you are using Microdata here which we are moving away from.

Comment: Oh, that's just me borrowing vocabulary wantonly. Of course use JSON-ld:

{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Corporation",
  "additionalType":"http://www.productontology.org/doc/Advertising_agency",
  [...]
}

Comment: Thank you very much. This works perfectly :-)